# Use SafeAreaView with react-native-webview

Tags: react-native

How can we use `SafeAreaView` in order to display a `WebView`? I tried this way :

```
import React from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, StatusBar} from 'react-native';
import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview';

class ChaineYT extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <WebView
          source={{uri: "someURL"}}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }
}

export default ChaineYT
```

But it's rendering a white page.

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You didn't specify the height and width of SafeAreaView.

Change `<SafeAreaView>` to `<SafeAreaView style={{ flex:1 }}>`

Official [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/height-and-width) clearly says:

> A component can only expand to fill available space if its parent has dimensions greater than 0. If a parent does not have either a fixed width and height or flex, the parent will have dimensions of 0 and the flex children will not be visible.

Comment: Thanks ! And is it possible to move down the bottom of the SafeAreaView ?

Comment: Move the WebView to the bottom of SafeAreaView?

Comment: Yeah I want to have a little space between the bottom bar of the iPhoneX and the webView. I don't know if I'm clear

Comment: You can add a bottom margin to the WebView using ```style={{marginBottom: '10%'}}```